# Mapeamento de entidades many to many com typeorm

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm

O que eu quero fazer é uma lista de todos os objetos que estão relacionados pelo ID com uma entidade.
Neste projeto, um grupo tem vários usuários e um usuário pertence a vários grupos.

**Entidade grupo:**

```
@Entity('group')
class Group {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column()
  name: string;

 @OneToMany(() => GroupMember, groupMember => groupMember.user, {
    eager: true,
  })
  @JoinTable()
  members: User[];

  @CreateDateColumn()
  created_at: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updated_at: Date;
}
```

**Entidade Usuário**

```
@Entity('user')
class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column()
  first_name: string;

  @Column()
  email: string;

  @OneToMany(() => GroupMember, groupMember => groupMember.group)
  @JoinTable()
  groups: Promise<Group[]>;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  @Exclude()
  created_at: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  @Exclude()
  updated_at: Date;
}
```

**Entidade Grupo-Usuário**

```
@Entity('group_member')
class GroupMember {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  group_id: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => Group, { primary: true })
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'group_id' })
  group: Promise<Group>;

  @PrimaryColumn()
  user_id: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => User, { primary: true })
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'user_id', referencedColumnName: 'id' })
  user: Promise<User>;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  created_at: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updated_at: Date;
}
```

O comportamento que eu espero é que, através do eager loading, eu obtenha uma lista de grupos quando eu buscar por um usuário e/ou obter uma lista de usuários quando eu buscar pelo grupo. O que eu estou obtendo atualmente são ambas listas vazias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui obter o resultado desejado fazendo da seguinte forma:

Na entidade group:

```js
@OneToMany(() => GroupMember, groupMember => groupMember.groups)
  members: GroupMember[];
```

Na entidade user

```js
@OneToMany(() => GroupMember, groupMember => groupMember.groups)
  groups: GroupMember[];
```

Na entidade group_users

```js
  @ManyToOne(() => Group, { primary: true })
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'group_id' })
  groups: Group[];

@ManyToOne(() => User, { primary: true })
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'user_id' })
  users: User[];
```

Aqui um exemplo de como carregar essas entidades pelo repositório de grupo:

```js
findById(group_id: string): Promise<Group | undefined> {
    return this.ormRepository.findOne(group_id, {
      relations: ['members', 'members.users'],
    });
  }
```